# Google Endpoints transformer for org.geolatte.geom.Point

Tags: java, jackson, google-cloud-endpoints

I have an entity that one of the properties is a location `org.geolatte.geom.Point<G2D>`. I created Google Endpoints `Transformer<Point<G2D>, String>` for it but I receive the following error:

> com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: Direct self-reference leading to cycle (through reference chain: com.example.package.MyEntity["location"]->org.geolatte.geom.Point["envelope"]->org.geolatte.geom.Envelope["coordinateReferenceSystem"]->org.geolatte.geom.crs.Geographic2DCoordinateReferenceSystem["coordinateSystem"]->org.geolatte.geom.crs.EllipsoidalCoordinateSystem2D["axes"]->org.geolatte.geom.crs.GeodeticLongitudeCSAxis["unit"]->org.geolatte.geom.crs.AngularUnit["fundamentalUnit"]->org.geolatte.geom.crs.AngularUnit["fundamentalUnit"])

Why Jackson is not being able to convert the property and how it should be done?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`org.geolatte.geom.Point` class extends `org.geolatte.geom.Geometry` which has `Envelope<P> getEnvelope()` method. `Jackson` by default serialises all `POJO` `getters`: `get*` and `is*` methods. You need to ignore these methods using `JsonIgnore` annotation. Example `MixIn` interface could look like below:

```
interface GeometryMixIn {

    @JsonIgnore
    Envelope getEnvelope();

    @JsonIgnore
    PositionSequence getPositions();
}
```

and now we need to register it as below:

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
mapper.addMixIn(Geometry.class, GeometryMixIn.class);
```

Now you can use this mapper to `Point` serialisation. In case, other `getters` would be problematic ignore them in the same way. But the best `OOP` way is to create custom `POJO` which we will create based on `Point` where we have full control what is visible for `3-rd party libraries`.

Answer (score 1):

I solve my problem by replacing `org.geolatte.geom.Point<G2D>` with `org.locationtech.jts.geom.Point`, but I don't know why Point does not work properly.